# Editing & saving .docx in ASP.NET program using OpenXML & MemoryStream

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, memorystream

I'm writing a project which allows you to edit .docx documents (I have a template that needs to be edited) directly from the site and save them to your computer.
I have a problem with saving all information I've already edited in file.

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    using (WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
    {
        string docText = null;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var senderData = Sender_Textbox.Text;
        var receiverData = Receiver_Textbox.Text;
        var subjectData = Subject_Textbox.Text;
        var contentData = Content_Textbox.Text;

        docText = ReplaceData(docText, "receiver", receiverData);
        docText = ReplaceData(docText, "sender", senderData);
        docText = ReplaceData(docText, "subject", subjectData);
        docText = ReplaceData(docText, "content", contentData);

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {
            sw.Write(docText);
        }
    }
    Session["ByteArray"] = memoryStream.ToArray();
}

static string ReplaceData(string docText, string oldText, string newText)
{
    var regexText = new Regex(oldText);
    return regexText.Replace(docText, newText);
}
```

I used [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/office/bb508261.aspx) tutorial from Office Dev Center, it works well in offline-solution. Part with StreamWriter doesn't work, and I download a document that has no changes at all. How can I save all information that I've edited online in wDoc?

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the updated document text to `StreamWriter sw` but then not doing anything with it.  You are then setting the session variable to your original, unedited byte array `memoryStream` (which is presumably why you're returning a document with no changes).

You need to convert `sw` to a byte array and put that in `Session["ByteArray"]` instead.

Also, a large byte array in a session variable does not seem like a terribly good idea.